# Identifying Importer Posts

Tags: post-meta, import, bulk-import

Given a site with 100 posts, where an unspecified number of posts are manually written, and the rest are created using the WordPress importer, how would I programmatically identify the posts imported without having access to remote sites or the original import file?

E.g. was this post created by the Importer tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I could imagine:

- Check the `post_modified` value. Maybe import creates a definitive timestamp that you could use. You'll still have to save the import date somewhere so you can check against it.
- I do some post importing via a stream/HTTP response (this is not the native importer). During the import, I map my [SysBot Plugin](https://gist.github.com/4636113) user to every post that has no existing user in the installation. This allows me to use archives, filter the admin post list table, etc. A very convenient solution to check those. It also allows posts that get reviewed to get out of the "imported but not touched yet"-queue as the author can change. You might also be able to use the native importer and use the `'import_allow_create_users'` with simply setting a callback of `__return_false`.
- Infiltrate the WP importer and attach a meta value during import. There's a hook that triggers for every imported post meta key named `'import_post_meta'`.

In case you're infiltrating the native importer plugin, you'd need to start at the `'import_start'` hook. The last hook in the system (where you might want to check if everything went fine), is the `'import_end'` hook.

### EDIT

I just encountered a class that I've not even known that it exists (in core, not the WP Importer plugin): `WP_Importer`. This class has a method, named `get_imported_posts()`.

So in theory you could do the following:

```
$importer = new WP_Importer;
$importer_name = '???';
$bid = get_current_blog_id();
$imported_posts = $importer->get_imported_posts( $importer_name, $bid );
```

The meta key that gets searched for is built by the two meta keys:

```
$meta_key = $importer_name . '_' . $bid . '_permalink';
```

So there *seems* to be a unique trace route that one can follow.

#### Update #2

An example query you could run would be:

```
var_dump( $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT post_id, meta_value 
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
    WHERE meta_key 
    LIKE '%_permalink%'
" ) );
```

This should bring all similar posts up an allow you to determine the "importer_name" easier.

#### Edit #3

There's `get_importers()`, which you can dump to see what importers are registered (using `register_importer()`). This should help identifying the actual importer name.

Comment: Marking as accepted as the last part provides a means of implementing this in future imports, though I'd say there's no foolproof method of doing it for past ones

Comment: @TomJNowell As you can see from the update, there _seems_ to be a foolproof way if you know your importer name. Whatever this is...

Answer (score 1):

While I am not aware of import doing anything explicit to mark the posts, the possible indicators are:

- `guid` field, if posts weren't imported from same domain (or some other differentiation)
- `post_id` field, which is suggested by `import_id` during import and can result in possibly detectable block of IDs that are not sequential to natively created ones